# Background full width not working

Tags: html, css

I have this code in general css

```
  #headtop {  width:100%; margin-top:-10px; background:url(link) 0 0 no-repeat; height:201px;}
```

And this one in media queries

```
  #headtop{padding-top:45%; height: auto;  }
```

I need to have a fluid background.. with full width and height. 
I tested on my tablet, ASUS and the problem is with the width, is half of image

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML code and create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce the issue, if possible.

Comment: When you say "fluid background", do you mean that you want the image to distort as necessary in order to see the full height and full width regardless of the window size? Or, do you want it more like this site [link](http://ringvemedia.com/) where the image proportions stay in tact but it fills the window?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background to span the full width and height of the window (which will create distortion in some windows) then you should modify the "background-size" of the element

```
#headTop { background-size: 100% 100%, auto auto;}
```

Comment: Would you like to add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: This isn't an answer really; it's a single line of code. Why not give some useful dialog on what op is doing wrong and why this supposedly works to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more descriptive in the future